# Downloading Images via PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP file called generate.php which generates a PNG email based on some parameters I set. The image can be displayed for example by using  which will return an image of "myString" text.

I would then like to add a link which allows the user to download the image:

I created a file download.php with the following code:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=string.png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile('generatePicture.php?string=' . $_REQUEST["string"]);
```

But, while I download a png file, I cannot seem to download. Any suggestions?

Comment: could you just include the generatePicture.php to call it?

Comment: This is an issue with the use of `readfile()`, because your script is attempting to open a file directly. You will need to make an HTTP request to that location and output the response.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that... Could you provide more information? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you readfile() a PHP file, its source is displayed. Below I'll show you my way to solve this problem.

Assuming `generatePicture.php` looks like:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
// work with the picture
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
?>
```

... it could be integrated with `download.php` this way:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
// work with the picture

if(isset($_GET['download']))
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=string.png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
?>
```

Now instead of linking to `download.php?string=loremipsum`, link to `generatePicture.php?string=loremipsum&download=1`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using this with moderate success for multiple file types. The main thing you need extracted from the file information is the file type, file name, and file size.

```
  header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
  header("Content-type:".$type);
  header("Content-Disposition: Attachment; Filename=".$name);
  header("Content-length:".$size);
  echo $data;
```

That might give you something different to try.

Comment: It's the `echo $data` part that is the trouble. The OP needs to read the data from an HTTP source and output it.

Answer (score -2):

Session locking. If you have two scripts that use `session_start()` the first script opens and locks the session's cache, and the second script must wait for the first to complete before it can open the cache.

If you have a long-running script that you don't want to monopolize a user's session, then either do not call `session_start()` for that script, or call [`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) after you've finished with the session data, but before you begin the long-running operation.

Either that, or use two different browsers to open two separate sessions.

Comment: ...but I never call session_start()